# IP redirection for apache in virtual hosts

Tags: apache2

Say I have two virtual hosts setup in apache.

> 1.domain.com points to var/www/1
>
> 2.domain.com points to var/www/2

What if someone enters the IP address of my server?

Is there a way to make the default location it takes them to? Or what will happen?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you cam make it.

Open the file /etc/apache2/sites-available/default

```
sudo gedit /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
```

navigate through the file to the line

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/
```

replace this with your path to be the default for example if you like /var/www/1, it becomes

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/1/
```

Now restart apache2

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Then open browser and enter your IP and enjoy

Comment: It only lists the directory and files instead I need my HTML file to be viewed